# How to handle unicode chars in Java

Tags: java, unicode, character, chars

I have been trying to achieve the following :

I want to be able to paste a string of Unicode characters ex :  without java showing them as being unrecognized. How do I make a Java JTextPane able to handle Unicode characters?

Comment: Java uses UTF-16 Unicode internally.  If you are seeing characters as unrecognized it's because you are not using a Unicode capable font in your `JTextPane`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use Unicode character you have to write it like this: **\u[unicode]**. So for example:

```
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "\u2764Guess number", "game", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

would produce the folowing: ❤Guess number. I hope i answered your question.

Comment: I just got my account 'unbanned' and I wanted to say a big thanks :)